# Run an API before page load Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using an API in main.js, Output of an API will be used on multiple pages and controllers using rootscope. So, I need to make sure that the API runs before any page gets loaded. Currently, Page gets loaded first and then API runs. Hence, I am unable to bind the APIs output to the html div.

Please Help!

Comment: You need to use resolve in your routes. But since you've provided no code or anything no one will be able to help you. Please update your question with the proper code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.... if you are assigning the result of the API to a `$rootScope` object, all pages/controllers using this object get automatically updated. Perhaps, you could add some sample code, what you get and what you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either an angular service to call the api and inject into the controller or use provider in the config and assign the data to `$rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
app.run(function($http, $rootScope){
  $http.get('CALL_TO_YOUR_API')
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $rootScope.config = data;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('API-loaded');
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
    alert('error');
  });
})

app.controller('MainControl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$on('API-loaded', function(){
//DO your stuff  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use resolve in config.js

```
.state('sampleState', {
                 url: "/sample",
                 templateUrl: "sample.html",
                 controller: 'SampleCtrl',
                 resolve: {
                     companyDetails : function($http) {
                         return $http.get('api/v1/get_sample')
                             .then(function (data) {
                              return data
                             }, function (data) {
                             });
                     }
                 }
             })
```